# SSH GITHUB Keys

Tags: git, ssh

I'm new to developing with GITHUB on a mac.  I have created the SSH public and private key files and have the public key in the settings on git hub.  I moved the files to the ~/.ssh folder on my mac.

The issue is that when I try to push to the remote branch, I get an access denied.

```
Jims-MacBook-Pro-2:romannumeralconverterAPI jrieck$ git push --set-upstream origin master
Enter passphrase for key '/Users/jrieck/.ssh/id_rsa': 
Enter passphrase for key '/Users/jrieck/.ssh/id_rsa': 
ERROR: Permission to jrieckPillarTechnology/ArabicToRomanNumeralAPI.git denied to deploy key
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
Jims-MacBook-Pro-2:romannumeralconverterAPI jrieck$
```

Any thoughts on the reason for the access denied error?

Comment: It looks like your key is protected with a passphrase, and you've entered it incorrectly.

Comment: Did you set up your personal key as a deploy key? Probably need to not do that.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you've set up your key as a deploy key, which are by default read-only. The idea behind a deploy key is that you can have an automated system use that key to access a specific repository for the purpose of deploying it to production. You can read more about why deploy keys are useful in the [GitHub documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/managing-deploy-keys/#deploy-keys).

If you're going to be using this key with your account as a human, not for an automated process, you probably want to remove it as a deploy key and instead add it as a key for your account, as described in the [GitHub documentation for adding an SSH key](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account/). Note that you'll need to remove the key as a deploy key first; if you don't, you won't be able to add it as a key for your account.